# Why does PHP say a microsecond is 1/10000th of a second?

Tags: php

As far as I know, a microsecond is 1/1000000th of a second (one millionth).
However for some reason, my php.exe v5.4.12 x64 (CLI on windows 7 x64) seems 'think' it is really 1/10000th (one thenthousand'th).

If I run the following php script:

```
<?php
while(true)
{
    echo microtime(true)."\r";
}
?>
```

The counter I see on screen never counts past .9999.
It jumps from 1381994204.9999 to 1381994205.0

I was going insane over this last night while writing a script that calculates something to a second, after realising this I changed the formula to divide the microtime(true) output by 10000 instead of 1000000 and it worked perfectly...

Comment: Your PC clock doesn't provide that much of precision anyway. So even if you had that - there is a chance you might get controversial results when the next timestamp is less than the previous http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx

Comment: @zerkms do not confuse "precision" with "accuracy".  A PC timer can easily be that _precise_, but is very rarely that _accurate_.

Comment: Why are you dividing it by anything at all? The return value is in seconds. Leave it as seconds.

Comment: @Alnitak: it's probably the language issue. I actually meant "accuracy" (or "resolution" - if I'm not confusing the terms once again). Anyway thanks for the correction

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

How about reading documentation as first?

Comment: @zerkms it's not just you - the doc page for that function makes the same mistake ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By setting the parameter to `true`, you are getting a float value – and that has a limited precision. `1381994986.3488` has 14 significant digits, and that is what you typically get with a [float](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

> *“The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).”*

When not setting the parameter, you can see that the values you are getting are actually microseconds - but you are getting them in string form.

Comment: Thanks! I see I should not use 'microsecond(true)' but just 'microsecond()' istead.

Comment: There really are some odd design decisions, this one however is caused by the need for backwards compatibility and not bad design.

Comment: @ToBe sure, but the decision to use `float` instead of `double` is flawed from the outset.

Comment: totally true! Had to use those bulky bc functions in the past because of that.

Comment: @Alnitak PHP's floats and doubles are the same 64-bit (double) type.